# CSRF for domain alias

Tags: csrf, django-csrf

I have a web site which is accessible under two separate domains, say `a.x.com` and `b.x.com`, or `a.com` and `a.org` (accomplished via a simple `ServerAlias` in apache).

The CSRF token can only be set to one of the domains (let's say `a.x.com`), so when accessing `b.x.com` I always get a 403: CSRF verification failed.

What is the proper way to handle domain aliases in the presence of CSRF tokens?

Answer (score 0):

Have you had a look at setting the `CSRF_COOKIE_DOMAIN` in the settings.py? Django docs for it are here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/#csrf-cookie-domain

Set it to '.x.com' and CSRF cookies for both subdomains will work on either.

Comment: That only works on sub-domains, right? How about the more common example of `x.com` vs `x.org`? As an owner of both, what is the django way of expressing trust between the two?

Comment: Yes it only works for subdomains, but it should be what you need for your question above. As for cross-domain, you can't do that with cookies (you can only set a cookie for a domain you're on) so the CSRF won't work - you'd have to come up with your own method of doing so.